# cannot pass spinner selected value android to php

Tags: php, android

i need to read data from external database with hundred of items.. so for i am trying to pass spinner selected value to php

android Activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.icd);

    spinnerCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCity);

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCity.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String data = spinnerCity.getSelectedItem().toString();

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // define the parameter
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("786", data));
            try {
                CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("786");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String response = null;

            // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters
            try {

                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(

                urlheart,
                ,       postParameters);

                // store the result returned by PHP script that runs
                // MySQL query
                String result = response.toString();

                // parse json data
                try {
                    returnString = "";
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag", "id: " + json_data.getInt("id")
                                + ", name: " + json_data.getString("name")

                        );
                        returnString += "\n" + "Name ="
                                + json_data.getString("icd_disease") + "\n"
                                + " Symptoms = "
                                + json_data.getInt("icd_symptoms") + "\n"
                                + "  "
                                + json_data.getString("icd_treatment");

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                try {
                    txt.setText(returnString);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in Display!" + e.toString());
                    ;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag",
                        "Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['786'])){
$id = $_POST['786'];

$sql = "SELECT icd_symptoms FROM icd WHERE icd_disease = 'id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

i m trying to pass value in this way, but its not working while before it i have done for button click but don't know why it is not working for spinner. please help. thanx in advance.

Comment: you are missing a $ at 'id', icd_disease = '$id'";... just saying

Comment: i write but still problem..

Comment: reading $_POST['786'];, but you are sending it as GET HttpGet("786")...

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to set onItemSlected for the spinner to get the selected item.

You are setting the adapter to spinner and same time trying to get the selected spinner item without any action listener

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter

        .createFromResource(this, R.array.city,

        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinnerCity.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String data = spinnerCity.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Fisrt liten to item selected in apinner and than do

```
String data = spinnerCity.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

within that.

Do one thing first just check if you are getting the selected value on spinner item selected or not. Just put below peace of code and keep log to print your valeu.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        // put log here to print you value selected
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: see my edited code , i have edited android activity like

Comment: Now where is the issue now?